# Emacs replace (*ptr_to_struct).member_var with ptr_to_struct->member_var

Tags: c, regex, emacs

Has anyone got an emacs regexp handy to do the following generic replacement?

```
(*ptr_to_struct).member_var to ptr_to_struct->member_var
```

where ptr_to_struct is any pointer to struct and member_var is any member variable

Comment: I don't think you need a regexp for that

Comment: `(*\w+).\w+` is about as far as I got - regexps are *fiendish*

Comment: `\((\*\)` matches the opening `(*` but then trying to add another group to get the struct pointer, e.g. `\((\*\)\(\w+\)` (which i could then refer to as `\2` in the replace bit, but it stops working at that point - not sure why

Comment: @Oli phew got there in the end - `M-x query-replace-regexp RET (\*\(\w+\)).\(\w+\) RET \1->\2` did the trick. Took me 45 mins but I think regexps will be my friend in the long run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to substitute `(\*\([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\))\.\([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\)` with `\1->\2`, where:

`[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*` catches the C identifier

`\(`...`\)` record a match for substitution

You can play with regular expression in Emacs using the integrated regexp builder: <kbd>M-x</kbd>`re-builder`.

Comment: @Hiett I have edited my answer to take care of identifier containing numbers

Comment: was just about to ask you that - you beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

Use replace-string:
`M-x replace-string" + return/Enter key`
then you should type in "(*ptr_to_struct).member_var" + return/Enter key
then you should type in "ptr_to_struct->member_var"   + reutrn/Enter key

Comment: hehe i'm not that stupid - my OP wasn't clear enough - have edited it